# mysql Search based on first alphabet

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am trying to search in database using below query

```
SELECT `name` FROM `food` WHERE `name` LIKE '%cheese%'
```

I have data in database like

```
apple cheese
cheese crust
cheese apple
apple crunch cheese
```

So when i use my query date are returned as it is,but i want to sort it based on first word..for example if i search for **cheese**, columns with cheese as first word should come in top

for example

```
   cheese crust
    cheese apple
    apple cheese
    apple crunch cheese
```

Comment: Are you always going to be searching for 'apple' or do you need a solution that works based on any word that you put in? Obviously you can do an alphabetical sort on 'apple' as chresse pointed out, but that isn't very flexible. Is that good enough?

Comment: no its dynamic.and alphabetic sort wont work.please see my edited question again..thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want the apple results first, but the fields that START with apple coming in "really first", then you'd need:

```
SELECT *
FROM food
WHERE name LIKE '%apple%'
ORDER BY (name LIKE 'apple%') DESC, name ASC
```

That'll sort all the "records that have apple" first, then within that, sort the records that START with apple to the top of the pile.

So you'd end up with

```
apple fries
apple fruit
cream,apple
cheese apple
apricot
```

Note that "apricot" comes after the apple-containing records.